# Calculate throughput and latency

Tags: latency

I have a project with a clock period of 5.9ns.  During simulation, it takes 233 clock cycles to produce the output.  Therefore, I calculated latency as 233*5.9 = 1347.7ns.

Given the latency, how do I calculate the throughput?  This is a non-pipelined design.

Comment: Reciprocate and convert to bits-per-second.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a non-pipelined design, then the throughput is just the number of results that can be calculated per second. If you now how long it takes to calculate one result, finding the throughput is just the reciprocal of that value.

Comment: The solution provides a 128-bit output every 1347.7ns.  

Therefore, every second I can produce (1000000000 (1 second)/1347.7 )* 128-bits

Is that correct?

Comment: And if it's a 233 registered pipeline, the throughput is just the clock rate, ~168 MHz, or ~168 million results/sec.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
\text{Throughput} &= \left(\frac{\text{Number of bits}}{\text{Result}}\right)\times \left(\frac{\text{Number of results}}{\text{Clock cycle}}\right)\times \left(\frac{\text{Number of clock cycles}}{\text{Time}} \right) \\
&= \frac{\text{Number of bits}}{\text{Time}} \\
&= \left( 128\frac{\text{Bits}}{\text{Result}}\right)\times\left(\frac{1 \text{ Result}}{233\text{ Clock Cycles}}\right) \times \left(\frac{1 \text{ Clock cycle}}{5.9\text{ ns}}\right) \\
&= 93.1\frac{\text{Mbits}}{\text{s}} \\
\end{align}
where "M" here stands for \$10^6\$.